# Colab ImportError for self-developed package

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory, importerror

I tried to import DataPreprocessor class in dgnfiai/gdnfiai/preprocessing/preprocessing.py my self-developed package gdnfiai into colab notebook but got ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessing' from 'gdnfiai' (unknown location). The package can be successfully imported on my laptop. I think maybe the problem is colab's default directory so I changed the directory on colab using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdnfiai/')
```

but still got the same error.

The structure of the package and my code for import is shown in the screenshot here:[image]

The exact steps I did are:

1. Open pipeline.ipynb notebook in colab. pipeline.ipynb is in gdnfiai/scripts folder in my package. But I uploaded it separately because I cannot run the notebook from cloned git repository.
2. Clone git repository gdnfiai.
3. `sys.path.append('/content/gdnfiai/')`
4. `pip install -e .`
5. Run `from gdnfiai.preprocessing.preprocessing import DataPreprocessor` and got ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to your typo in the `preprocessing` directory, with the filename `__inti__.py`. Rename it to `__init__.py`, as in your other directories.